# how to use getprocadderss to a struct or STL

Tags: c++, struct, dll, stl

I am pretty new to DLL:s and I've tried using a DLL with static link and dynamic link but this is my first time using runtime link (which uses `LoadLibrary` in order to access) and now I am trying to use my global `std::vector` in my `client.exe` is it possible to do `GetProcAddress()` to get this STL? or is it possible to `GetProcAddress` some struct that stored in DLL?

Comment: You can write a function that returns your `std::vector`, then import it using `GetProcAddress`.

Comment: cant do it with extern "C" ? and access violation?

Comment: While you can return a pointer to a `std::vector` that you constructed inside the DLL, you must make sure that the user of the DLL uses the same definition of `std::vector`. That's not easy (I don't even think it's possible to do safely). You can create your own classes (so you know the definition fits) and with some care make sure that destruction of objects created inside the DLL are also done inside the DLL. The DLL and the user may not use the same `malloc`/`free` as you have inside the DLL so that's important too. It's really not easy to do this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `stl::vector` is global to the application you can simply pass a reference to a function within the DLL.

If the `stl::vector` is global with respect to the DLL then you can have a function in the DLL return a reference to it.  However, as stated already, if there is a chance the DLL and the application could be compiled using different versions of the STL then there is potential for issues, but you would probably be using a DLL compiled sometime in the past.  Crossing C++ specs is most likely the main concern.  If the application and the DLL are compiled at the same time then there is no concern.